# Windows Server 2012 R2 in AWS EC2, change resolution beyond 1280x1024

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, screen-resolution

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance running in EC2 performing some UI tests while nobody is connected to it. I use the following script to disconnect from Remote Desktop:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%s in ('query user %USERNAME%') do (
  %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%s /dest:console
)
```

The instance is using the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter driver which has a maximum resolution of 1280x1024. I would like to use 1920x1200 resolution if possible.

I've tried the following hack to upgrade the driver to a patched version using [this process](https://ywjheart.wordpress.com/2014/04/19/modify-microsoft-basic-display-driver-to-get-a-better-resolution/).

But it doesn't work, maybe because the drivers are different, or maybe because the server is not really "headless" (see the process above).

Is there any way I could increase the resolution on EC2 Windows Server 2012 R2 instances without using the instances with graphics card? I do not need acceleration, just higher resolution.

Comment: were you able to find a solution?

Comment: If you need it larger because your automated testing needs a bigger window, you might be able to [programmatically make the window larger than the desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445893/create-window-larger-than-desktop-display-resolution). Of course, whether you can do this will depend on what your exact needs are, but it might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

One option that i am aware of is not a really god one, but resolves the issue: create RDP connection from instance to itself and it will force it to use reflected display driver provided by RDP so you will be able to specify resolution using mstsc parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum resolution offered by the server is limited by the video card RAM size server side.

In your case you would need to get the video card upgrade as you don’t control the hardware layer nor the hypervisor.

Standard VGA driver are often limited, but are nore than able to deliver for standard scenario.